# Magento catalog price rule more then 100%

Tags: php, magento

I want to apply 120% dicount, for example if price is 50$ then with 120% it will be 60$, I tried  to change `app\code\core\Mage\CatalogRule\Helper\data.php`

`public function calcPriceRule($actionOperator, $ruleAmount, $price)`, but it didnt give any change. Any advice ?

Comment: Doesn't 120% discount make a negative price? I think you mean a negatieve discount.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean a negative discount, 
It can be done via going to this path and edit `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Catalog/Edit/Tab/action.php`

comment this line:

```
'class' => 'validate-not-negative-number',
```